# How do I output a Rails logger in Delayed_Jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I would like to log `@cf` in this delayed_job :

```
(CardReferral.all.map(&:email).map(&:downcase) - CardSignup.all.map(&:email).map(&:downcase)).each do |cf|
  @cf = CardReferral.find_by_email(cf)
  # <--- I  want to add a Rails logger here
  Notifier.deliver_referred_magic_email(User.find(@cf.user_id), @cf.email, @cf.name, @cf.message, subject, editor1)
end
```

Rails version in **Rails 2.3.5**  .

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused; what's the question? Is there a problem using the standard logger?

Comment: No, I just don't know how to write the logger statement or where to find it in documentation.

Comment: this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html is for Rails 3, not Rails 2.3.5. Know where I can find documentation for logging in that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logger is accessible through the "logger" command in your models and controllers. You can call one of its methods to specify your message's log level (debug, info, warn, error, fatal), like this:

```
logger.debug("This will be logged")
```

You can find more in the Rails guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger).

Comment: Does this work in delayed_jobs? Many thanks for the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

It actually doesn't, add this in your task:

```
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```